# Issues with Bootstrap Modal Window

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

first time posting on here. I've searched thru the site and couldn't find an answer to this issue I'm having so I hope someone may have an idea:

The issue is, when clicking the 'contact' link on the homepage, the modal window shows with content (i.e. buttons / text) but the screen turns grey and is unresponsive when clicking the 'close' button.

```
<div class = "modal fade" id = "contact" role = "dialog">
    <div class = "modal-dialog">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <h4>Contact Tech Site</h4>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class = "btn btn-primary" data-dismiss = "modal">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

To be clear, this is what my page looks like after clicking the 'contact' link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8etlue21jfk1ti/Screenshot%202014-06-24%2017.54.27.png

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where's the button/link that launches the modal? Can you post that code? Also, you have an extra `</div>`

Comment: <li><a href = "#contact" data-toggle = "modal">Contact</a></li>

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you're code is doing, I'd venture to guess the "gray color" is actually a div with a fixed position with a z-index greater than that of the modal. Have you tried manually setting the z-index of the modal to a higher value?

Comment: It looks ok and works ok on bootply http://www.bootply.com/26jF4ICLl7 so the problem might be elsewhere, prob not in the code you posted

Comment: Okay. Well that's good news. I'm just learning Bootstrap and followed almost line for line from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YJUFaZMS8Q As far as elsewhere, any idea what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Post all your code to be review.. I've seen an extra `</div>` there and what ever other codes you have might be the reason but your code posted is ok when i tested it..

Comment: Open Developer Tools in your browser, find the Console window and reload the page, walk thru the process until it freezes.  Console will shed light on the problem.

Comment: do you have any custom css happening, or other libraries in play?

Comment: Just to be sure (because I have made this mistake before). Are you including Bootstrap in a single header file? or at the top of the page. If you get into a bad habit of including things more than once, it can get sloppy. If you are using the CDN, try downloading the full Bootstrap in including it in your library.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6622/ Hey guys, here is the code in entirety (you have to expand the window to see navigation links). I have tried all suggestions, but no progress thus far. To clarify, modal window shows up in grey (which is part of the problem), but buttons seem to be functional on js fiddle. On my browser, the page just freezes when the window appears.

Comment: I didn't add head tags on js fiddle. Here they are: <head>
 <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
 <link href = "css/bootstrap.css" rel = "stylesheet">

 <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>

Comment: Not using CDN but full bootstrap download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues. You have not closed `div`s, `ul`s in navbar. Also, you have not commented this line properly `<!-- maximum 12 grids i.e. no more than 4x "col-md-3" -->` etc. In detail:

1. You have not closed the `div` for this div `<div class="navbar navbar-primary navbar-static-top">`.
2. Not closed the `ul` for this ul `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`.
3. Not closed the `div` for the modal div `<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">`

http://fiddle.jshell.net/52VtD/6726/show/ Modal is working fine.

**Bottom Line**

To get what you expected, your HTML must be clean and semantic without missing any closing elements,

Comment: That works! Thank you. I hadn't realized there was a missing div tag even in the original code (i though it was just a miscue from the snippet). I also noticed your script tags were listed in the header rather than at the bottom. Whether or not that was an issue, I edited it accordingly and the modal is working fine now. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Since it is a fiddle, it might put the scripts in head. However, the best practice is always use scripts just before to the body tag.